# iOS - Only some cells get loaded in UITableView, while the rest don't appear until after scrolling through them

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app that downloads data from Parse.

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
          [self getData];
    }
```

in the getData method, after all data is downloaded it calls self.tableView reloadData on the main thread:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
```

But only the first cell updates correctly, while the rest are left to their placeholder values until I scroll through them.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

if (indexPath.row == 0){

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIButton *signUp = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    signUp.clipsToBounds = YES;
    signUp.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    [signUp addTarget:self
               action:@selector(toSignUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [signUp setHidden:NO];


    UILabel *spotsOutOf500 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    spotsOutOf500.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",onSpot,ofSpots];
    [spotsOutOf500 setHidden:NO];


    UILabel *spotsLeft = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    spotsLeft.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d spots left",ofSpots - onSpot];
    if (ofSpots - onSpot < 0){
        spotsLeft.text = @"0 spots left";
    }
    [spotsLeft setHidden:NO];

    return cell;
}

if (indexPath.row == 1){


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIButton *getRobin = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
    getRobin.clipsToBounds = YES;
    getRobin.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    [getRobin addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(getRobin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    UIButton *sendToFriend = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
    sendToFriend.clipsToBounds = YES;
    sendToFriend.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    [sendToFriend addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(sendToFriend) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];




    return cell;


}



static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


PFObject *stock = stocks[indexPath.row-2];
   // int row = indexPath.row;
   // NSLog (@"%@,%d",stock,row);
UILabel *ticker = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
ticker.text = stock[@"ticker"];

UILabel *dateAndTime = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1002];
dateAndTime.text = stock[@"dateAndTime"];



return cell;
```

}

I have been stuck on this for 4 days. Thank you for your help.

EDIT this is the getData method:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Stock"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAtEST"];
[query setLimit:25];
[query whereKey:@"live" equalTo:@"true"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    stocks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];
    for (int i = 0; i < stocks.count; i++){
        if (![stocks[i][@"sold"] boolValue]){
            [stocks removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            i--;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stocks.count; i++){
        NSLog(@"%@",stocks[i][@"ticker"]);
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });        
}];
```

Comment: also, when I debug it. I can see that the data passed to each cell is correct. Maybe I should try to redraw the cells? I have tried cell setNeedDisplay in the cellForRowAtIndexPath but nothing.

Comment: You are calling `reloadData` before you set the data that is to be reloaded.

Comment: What do you mean by set the data? How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe you should post your `getData` method. I can't see how you're storing your data.

Comment: Added to question. Thank you

Comment: Try reloadData when `findObjectsInBackground` is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the Storyboard Layout to Any x Any

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Why did it worked before when after scrolling.

Comment: I'm not sure but it had something do with the autolayout

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[self getData];` in

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self getData];
}
```

Also, I would fix your cellForRow like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (indexPath.row == 0){

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        }
        // Do your set up
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        }
        // Do your set up
    }
    else {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        // Get data from your datasource
        // Do your set up
    } 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Using your method, only the visible stocks were loaded successfully. But, when I scroll down all the cells are empty. Only after scrolling back up and then down again all the data appears.

Comment: @LeonardoMurri Have you tried calling `getData` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` ?

Answer (score 0):

Last line in getData is  [self.tableView reloadData] and whole function is happening in back thread. 
So, I would assume that you're trying to manipulate with table view from two threads that could lead to some kind of lock. 
I would remove that line from the getData or execute it in the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

This is in Swift Syntax, but I believe the same attributes are available.

On your tableview, use the attributes

`tableview.beginupdates()` and `tableview.endUpdates()`

This should update the tableview dynamically without having to scroll. Preferably, add these when a new cell is being entered to the tableview itself. Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't do anything,,,